# Enviar parametros via post json android

Tags: android, api, http

> Preciso enviar a string username via post depois do button1 ser clicado, meu código não tem nenhum erro no monitor,simplesmente não envia nada ao banco...Este é meu codigo :

```
public class PostTeste extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button1;
    private EditText username;
    String  mUsername;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpost);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
                // String  mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                //tryLogin(mUsername);

                new TryLogin().execute("Samara");
            }
        });
    }

    private class TryLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            final String mUsername = params[0];
            if (null == mUsername) {
                return "Username não informado";
            }

            HttpURLConnection connection;
            OutputStreamWriter request = null;

            URL url = null;
            String response = null;
            String parameters = "email=" + mUsername;

            try {
                url = new  URL("api_url");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", "key");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "auth");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write(parameters);
                request.flush();
                request.close();
                String line = "";
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.
                response = sb.toString();
            /**
             Não podemos interar com a tela!, vamos mandar para o método onPostExecute
             */
            // Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server:"+ response, 0).show();
                isr.close();
                reader.close();
                return response;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.getMessage();
            }

        }

    /**
     * Este método irá rodar na Thread de UI após executar a ação!
     *
     * @param s
     */

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (s != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ola,
O url.openConnection(); apenas cria o objeto, para realizar a conexão de fato adicione o seguinte código após o request.close() :
`connection.connect();`

Comment: Poderia esclarecer mais sobre onde colocar o código e o que ele faz?

Comment: Editei no post ;)